# Having FPS lags when drawing tiles in XNA

Tags: xna-4.0, lag, frame-rate

I am developing my own tile-based game in xna 4.0, and i suffer big fps lags while drawing the tiles on the screen.
I've read a lot about increasing performance and i've got to this:

I store my tiles in a simple dictionary

```
private Dictionary<Vector2, IBlock> WorldBlocks;
private Vector2 ExactBlockPosition;
private IBlock ExistingBlock;

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch SpriteBatch, Vector2 ScreenStart, Vector2 ScreenEnd)
    {
        // Run over all the blocks in the screen
        for (this.ExactBlockPosition.X = this.GetCurrentBlockXPosition(ScreenStart.X);
             this.ExactBlockPosition.X < ScreenEnd.X;
             this.ExactBlockPosition.X += Global.BLOCK_WIDTH)
        {
            for (this.ExactBlockPosition.Y = this.GetCurrentBlockYPosition(ScreenStart.Y);
                 this.ExactBlockPosition.Y < ScreenEnd.Y;
                 this.ExactBlockPosition.Y += Global.BLOCK_HEIGHT)
            {
                // Check if there is a block in the exact block location
                if (this.WorldBlocks.TryGetValue(this.ExactBlockPosition, out this.ExistingBlock))
                {
                    // Draw the block on the screen
                    this.ExistingBlock.Draw(SpriteBatch);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int GetCurrentBlockXPosition(float X)
    {
        return (int)(X - X % Global.BLOCK_WIDTH);
    }

    private int GetCurrentBlockYPosition(float Y)
    {
        return (int)(Y - Y % Global.BLOCK_WIDTH);
    }
```

In short, this code is drawing the blocks that are on the screen only.
But still my fps falls to 31 when there is a lot of tiles on the screen.
The tile width and heigh is 20 pixels.
Any suggestions why my fps falls?

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with sprite batches in XNA,  However, I know that whenever you have a mass of things you need to draw in OpenGL/DirectX that are roughly the same but vary in slight ways (UV's , texture difference, bone positioning) you batch them so that they are done so that there is kind of a single draw call.  Conversely, if you are drawing a grid, you pack all the vertexes into a single buffer and then draw that buffer.  It *looks* like separate objects, but it's under a single draw call.  I don't know if this helps, but there may be useful ideas.  How many is "a lot" of tiles?

Comment: The number of tiles drawed is depended on the screen resolution, for instance i have 1920x1080 resolution and every tile is 20x20 so the maximum drawed tiles number is 1920 / 20 * 1080 / 20 which is exactly 5184 tiles, but there are never 5184 tiles on the screen because i generate the tiles randomly so it can even draw 0 tiles when i am in a place where no tiles are visible. The fps lags suddenly appear in random places, and i dont understand what could be the reason for that...

Comment: please show us your `ExistingBlock.Draw(SpriteBatch)` function

Comment: spriteBatch.Draw(this.Texture, this.Position, Color.White);